# Getting "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 500" error while invoking GCP apigw-2.com/api2 from GCP cloud run micro-1.com/api1

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-api-gateway

At present we have the below integration flow

angular app -> GCP apigw-1.com/api1 -> GCP cloud run micro-1.com/api1 -> GCP cloud run apigw-2.com/api2

we can invoke below without issues

1. angular app -> GCP apigw-1.com/api1 -> GCP cloud run micro-1.com/api1
2. directly GCP cloud run apigw-2.com/api2 from postman

however, when GCP cloud run micro-1.com/api1 -> GCP cloud run apigw-2.com/api2 is invoked we get apigw-2.com getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 500 internal server error

Please let me know if there is any special config is required at GCP side to allow micro-1.com/api1 to invoke apigw-2.com/api2?

Comment: The URL/hostname is incorrect or does not exist in DNS. If you are trying to network from one Cloud Run instance to another, then you must use the Cloud Run service URL. Also try suggestions from these [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58993308/18265570) and [link2](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/AI-ML/Error-getaddrinfo-ENOTFOUND-dialogflow-googleapis-com/m-p/632861)

Comment: We are trying to invoke apigw-2.com/api2 (which is GCP API gateway) from micro-1.com/api (which is a nodejs microservice on GCP cloud run).  Not able to understand what special setting we need to configure to let nodejs microservice consume api gateway where both of them belong to the same GCP project.

Comment: The message **ENOTFOUND** is a DNS failure, which means the gateway can't resolve the host with the given hostname. Check [this article](https://www.squash.io/how-to-fix-node-js-getaddrinfo-enotfound-error/) for possible solution. Also share additional logs if possible.